# How to calculate $\int _0^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus

can someone give me a hint on how to calculate this integral?

$\int _0^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Amzoti can we solve it analytically?

Comment: @Amzoti thanks for apply. So is there any way for us to tell whether a integral is solvable analytically?

Comment: @EEEV I believe not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the upper limit would have been $1$ instead of $\dfrac13$ , then the definite integral could have been

expressible in terms of [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) $\Big($just let $x=\sin t$, and then use the fact that $\sin^2t=$

$\dfrac{1-\cos2t}2\bigg)$. But, as it stands, one would need “incomplete” Bessel functions to express its

value. Unfortunately, such functions do not exist. Alternately, one might expand the integrand

into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and switch the order of summation and integration, in the hope of

obtaining a [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^\frac{1}{3}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~dx$

$=\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}\dfrac{e^{-\sin^2x}}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}~d(\sin x)$

$=\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}e^\frac{\cos2x-1}{2}~dx$

$=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^{2\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}e^\frac{\cos x}{2}~d\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$

$=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}\int_0^{2\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}e^\frac{\cos x}{2}~dx$

Which can express in terms of [Incomplete Bessel Functions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9C572E5CE44E9E0DE8630755DF99ABAC/S0013091505000490a.pdf/incomplete-bessel-functions-i.pdf)