# Integral of $\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck at an integral $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

My attempt is substitute the $x=\sin t$, however there may be no primitive function of $e^{-\sin^2 t}$.

So does this integral has a definitive value? If does, how can we solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Of course it has a definitive value...it is the area under a continuous curve.

Comment: did you try $1-x^2  = t$?

Comment: Very likely there is no closed-form expression for the value, which is $\sim 0.3274711440$...

Comment: Wolfram-Alfha give no closed form.

Comment: @fretty Yeah...En, my point is the some kind form of the value.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159599).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not seem that a closed form exist. To evaluate the integral, start with a Taylor expansion which gives $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3 x^4}{8}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ So you are let with the weighted sum of integrals $$I_n=\int x^{2n}e^{-x^2}\,dx$$ which lead to gamma functions. For the given bounds, the sum seems to converge very quickly to the value given by Travis (only four terms required for six significant digits).

Comment: Still,it wouldn't have close form right?

Comment: For me, no closed form ... but I may be wrong !!

Comment: May I add that you could use 
$$I_n = (-1)^n\dfrac{d^{n}}{d\alpha^n}\int \mathrm{e}^{-\alpha x^2}dx$$ which depending on limits the closest closed form (if you could call it that) is the cumulative distribution. Though I could be wrong ;).

Comment: @Chinny84. Why don't you add that as an answer ? It is very interesting. Cheers :-)

Comment: Because it only compliments your answer. So I much prefer if the comment is logical to add to your fine answer (I would not of got to the conclusion above without your work). Thanks :)

Comment: @Chinny84. This is one of the reasons for which I enjoy so much this site : we cooperate, we work all together ! It is not the first time I really appreciate your answer, comments and attitude. Thank you ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I totally agree with your statement. You have provided me with many resources to expand my "mathematical toolbox" :).

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\arcsin\frac{1}{3}}\exp\left(-\sin^2\theta\right)\,d\theta \tag{1}$$
but since:

$$ \exp(-\sin^2\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\left(I_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\sum_{n\geq 1}I_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos(2n\theta)\right)\tag{2} $$
we have:
$$ I = e^{-1/2}\left(\arcsin\frac{1}{3}\right) I_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+e^{-1/2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{3n}\, I_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)U_{2n-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{8}{9}}\right)\tag{3}$$
where $I_m$ is a [modified Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and $U_k$ is a [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html).

Answer (score 1):

Approach $1$:

$\int_0^\frac{1}{3}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

$=\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}\dfrac{e^{-\sin^2t}}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2t}}d(\sin t)$

$=\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}e^{-\sin^2t}~dt$

$=\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin^{2n}t}{n!}dt$

$=\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin^{2n}t}{n!}\right)dt$

For $n$ is any natural number,

$\int\sin^{2n}t~dt=\dfrac{(2n)!t}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}t\cos t}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}+C$

This result can be done by successive integration by parts.

$\therefore\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin^{2n}t}{n!}\right)dt$

$=\left[t+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t}{4^n(n!)^3}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}t\cos t}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^3(2k-1)!}\right]_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t}{4^n(n!)^3}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}t\cos t}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^3(2k-1)!}\right]_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{3}}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!\sin^{-1}\dfrac{1}{3}}{4^n(n!)^3}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{2\sqrt2(-1)^n(2n)!((k-1)!)^2}{4^{n-k+1}9^k(n!)^3(2k-1)!}$

Approach $2$:

$\int_0^\frac{1}{3}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{1}{9}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}d(\sqrt{x})$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{1}{9}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{9}}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{9}}\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x}{9}}}d\left(\dfrac{x}{9}\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{6}\int_0^1\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{9}}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x}{9}}}dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{3}\Phi_1\left(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{2};\dfrac{1}{9},-\dfrac{1}{9}\right)$ (according to [About the confluent versions of Appell Hypergeometric Function and Lauricella Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812748))